# For which values of $α \in \mathbb R$ is the matrix $A$ diagonally dominant. Justify.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Let the matrix $A \in R
^{n×n}$. Then:

• $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant if $|A(i, i)| > \sum_{j=1,j \not= i}^n |A(i, j)|$ for all $i = 1, 2,..., n.
$

• $A $is diagonally dominant if  $|A(i, i)| \geq \sum_{j=1,j \not= i}^n |A(i, j)|$ for all $i = 1, 2,..., n$.

• If $A$ is symmetric strictly diagonally dominant matrix with positive diagonal entries $(A(i, i) > 0, i = 1 : n)$,
then $A$ is positive definite.

Let $A = C+α||C||_ ∞I$ where $C$ is any real $n×n$ matrix. For which values of $α \in \mathbb R$ is the matrix $A$ diagonally
dominant. Justify. For which values of $α \in \mathbb R$ is the matrix $A$ strictly diagonally dominant. Justify.

My attempt:

$|A(i, i)| = |C(i, i) + \alpha||C(i, i)||_ ∞I(i, i) | = |C(i, i) + \alpha||C(i, i)||_ ∞|$ since $I(i, i) = 1$

And $|A(i, j)| = |C(i, j) + \alpha||C(i, j)||_ ∞I(i, j) | = |C(i, j)|$ since $I(i, j) = 0$ for $i \not= j$.

Then $A$ is diagonally dominant if $|C(i, i) + \alpha||C(i, i)||_ ∞| \geq \sum_{j=1,j \not= i}^n|C(i, j)|$

And $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant if $|C(i, i) + \alpha||C(i, i)||_ ∞| > \sum_{j=1,j \not= i}^n|C(i, j)|$

But I didn't know how to proceed from there to get $\alpha$. Any help please?

Comment: there's a problem here... selecting $C=\mathbf 0$  makes the solution for $\alpha$ the empty set.  As for $C\neq \mathbf 0$, it should be reasonably easy to see this holds for $\alpha \gt 1$ but if e.g. $\alpha =1$ you should be able to generate an example of mere non-strict diagonal dominance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\|C\|_\infty = \max_{1\le i \le n} \sum_{i=1}^n |C(i,j)|$. For $|\alpha| \ge 1$ we have

$$|A(i,i)| = |C(i,i)+\alpha \|C\|_\infty| \ge |\alpha|\|C\|_\infty - |C(i,i)| \ge \|C\|_\infty - |C(i,i)| \ge\\
\ge \sum_{i=1}^n |C(i,j)| - |C(i,i)| = \sum_{i=1,i\ne j}^n |C(i,j)| =  \sum_{i=1,i\ne j}^n |A(i,j)|$$

so $A$ is diagonally dominant. Similarly, for $\alpha > 1$, assuming $C \ne 0$, we see that $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant.

If $|\alpha| < 1$ then $A$ in general doesn't have to be diagonally dominant, e.g. with $$C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$