# For which values of $α \in \mathbb R$ is the matrix $A$ strictly diagonally dominant? Justify

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let the matrix $A \in \mathbb R
^{n×n}$. Then:

• $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant if $|A(i, i)| > \sum_{j=1,j \not= i}^n |A(i, j)|$ for all $i = 1, 2,..., n.
$

• $A $is diagonally dominant if  $|A(i, i)| \geq \sum_{j=1,j \not= i}^n |A(i, j)|$ for all $i = 1, 2,..., n$.

• If $A$ is symmetric strictly diagonally dominant matrix with positive diagonal entries $(A(i, i) > 0, i = 1 : n)$,
then $A$ is positive definite.

Let $A = C + α||C||_∞I$ where $C$ is a real $n×n$ matrix with positive diagonal entries $(C(i, i) > 0, i = 1 : n)$.

For which values of $α \in \mathbb R$ is the matrix $A$ strictly diagonally dominant? Justify

My attempt:

Note that: $||C||_∞ = max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |C(i, j)|$

$|A(i, i)| = |C(i, i) + \alpha||C(i, i)||_ ∞I(i, i) | = |C(i, i) + \alpha||C(i, i)||_ ∞|$ since $I(i, i) = 1$

And $|A(i, j)| = |C(i, j) + \alpha||C(i, j)||_ ∞I(i, j) | = |C(i, j)|$ since $I(i, j) = 0$ for $i \not= j$.

$A$ is strictly diagonally dominant if $|C(i, i) + \alpha||C(i, i)||_ ∞| > \sum_{j=1,j \not= i}^n|C(i, j)|$

But I didn't know how to proceed from there to get $\alpha$. Any help please?

Comment: Consider [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3917219/144766) to this exact question from yesterday.

Comment: This is not the same question

Comment: What happens if you try to apply the same answer?